# Add a column of DateTime to an existing dataframe

Tags: julia

I have the following DataFrame:

```
using DataFrames, Dates

df = DataFrame( A=Int[], B=Int[] )
push!(df, [1, 10])
push!(df, [2, 20])
push!(df, [3, 30])

df[!, :C] .= DateTime()

for r in eachrow(df)
    # Super complex function, simplified for example
    r.C = now() + Day(r.A)
end
```

But `df[!, :C] .= DateTime()` does not create a column with DateTime's (I want just to allocate the column, actual DateTimes will be populated via for i in eachrow loop).

Comment: It is better if your MWE:
Minimal: ei.g,. the `MyStruct` is never used,
and Working (baring the error itself)
e.g `df[! :C]` should be `df[!, :C]`
`eachrow` should be `eachrow(df)`
`i` should be `r`.

and an runable Example,
so could include `mySuperComplexFunctionThatReturnsDateTimeForEachRow(r) = now() + Day(r.A)`

Comment: I agree, it was not the best example on how to formulate a question here. At least, I will edit the question and remove the MyStruct definition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no method `DateTime()`, try

```
df[!, :C] .= DateTime(0)
```

instead.

Answer (score 2):

While [@Daniel's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58006784/179081) is correct to question as asked.

You could replace your `for` loop with a `map`,
and avoid having to preallocate.

```
df.C = map(eachrow(df) do r
    # Super complex function, simplified for example
    return now() + Day(r.A)
end
```